# Select line not selecting whitespace

Tags: text-processing, vim, editors, productivity

Is there a way to select (or paste) text without trailing/ending whitespace?

eg. To copy the whole line I press `y`, to paste it somewhere else I use `p`,
but it pastes the whole text with the trailing EOL character too.

The same case using Windows standard:
home, shift+end, ctrl+c, ctrl+v
(allows me to paste the selected text inline)

I'd like to have similar behavior in vim.
I'd like to avoid any macros, as I'm using PHPStorm plugin emulating vim, so not all sophistocated command are working there.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of yanking the entire line (with the trailing newline) with `yy`, use `0y$` instead.

If you want no surrounding whitespace at all, `_yg_` would be possible in Vim.